# protecting selenium from detection

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to crawl a couple of website pages to use their information and I can only use things like selenium that has chromium to do that

Now I am trying to hide it from the website owners because I don't want to get banned. some people are talking about changing some variable names called cdc_ inside of chromdriver and I can't understand how to do it

Also I am using python for this

EDIT : My problem is that I can't change the variable of cdc_ or any other variables in chrome driver because I don't know how

any method so I can hide the fact that I am using selenium!

Please help me here

Thank you for your time

Comment: No , There is a website that has some charts about stock prices and I want to create a software to process them. so I need to scrap that webpage first

Comment: those charts and tables will be updated every second

Comment: https://iextrading.com/developer/ || https://www.alphavantage.co || https://intrinio.com

Comment: thank you but this website has other information like their indicators and others

Comment: I have seen that page but I can't change that variable, I don't know how to do that

Comment: use hex editor.